# How to number equations within theorem-like environments

Tags: equations, numbering, theorems

I want to enumerate equations within theorem-like environments.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
%
\begin{document}
\section{Natural Numbers}
\begin{theo} 
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
1+1=2.
\end{equation}
\begin{proof}
The proof of the equation~\eqref{eq:1} is left as an exercise.
\end{proof}
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

And produce something like

[image]

Comment: Your code has some (easy to fix) errors and won't work. Please fix it. On your question, how would you number equations that appear outside a theorem?

Comment: My purpose is enumerate equations only in the proofs; because outside I use an 'observation' environment or just $$ $$

Comment: I've updated my answer providing a simpler solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once `amsmath` has been loaded, you can use

```
\numberwithin{equation}{theorem}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{theo}

\begin{document}

\section{Natural Numbers}
\begin{theo} 
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
1+1=2.
\end{equation}
\begin{proof}
The proof of the equation~\eqref{eq:1} is left as an exercise.
\end{proof}
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you're sure that you'll be using numbered equations only within theorem environments (and other theorem-like environments) and if you're loading the `amsmath` package, you could issue the command

```
\numberwithin{equation}{theorem}
```

where `theorem` is the environment set up with a `\newtheorem` statement.

If you have several theorem-like environments, be sure to have them share the same counter. How to do this depends strongly on the theorem package that's in use. For the `amsthm` package, you'd force the `lemma`, `corollary`, etc environments to use the same counter as `theorem` environments do by issuing commands such as

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corrolary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\numberwithin{equation}{theorem}
```

By the way, don't use the deprecated `$$ ... $$` method to create unnumbered display-style equations. Instead, use something like `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`. Among other good things, the spacing around displayed equations will become much better.